# SVG sprite in external file

Tags: html, svg, sprite

I'm using an icon system for my app with SVG Sprite, created by IcoMoon App.
In index.html I have now something like this:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
<svg display="none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="752" height="80" viewBox="0 0 752 80">
    <defs>
    <g id="icon-home">
        <path class="path1" d="M32 18.451l-16-12.42-16 12.42v-5.064l16-12.42 16 12.42zM28 18v12h-8v-8h-8v8h-8v-12l12-9z" />
    </g>
    <g id="icon-camera">
        <path class="path1" d="M9.5 19c0 3.59 2.91 6.5 6.5 6.5s6.5-2.91 6.5-6.5-2.91-6.5-6.5-6.5-6.5 2.91-6.5 6.5zM30 8h-7c-0.5-2-1-4-3-4h-8c-2 0-2.5 2-3 4h-7c-1.1 0-2 0.9-2 2v18c0 1.1 0.9 2 2 2h28c1.1 0 2-0.9 2-2v-18c0-1.1-0.9-2-2-2zM16 27.875c-4.902 0-8.875-3.973-8.875-8.875 0-4.902 3.973-8.875 8.875-8.875 4.902 0 8.875 3.973 8.875 8.875 0 4.902-3.973 8.875-8.875 8.875zM30 14h-4v-2h4v2z" />
    </g>
    </defs>
</svg>   
...some html code...
<!-- an image -->
<svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="#icon-home"></use></svg>
</body>
<html>
```

I need to move the svg sprite in a file and then include it as an external resource.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

Create an `SVG` file, sprites.svg

Place the following in it:

```xml
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <path id="icon-home" class="path1" d="M32 18.451l-16-12.42-16 12.42v-5.064l16-12.42 16 12.42zM28 18v12h-8v-8h-8v8h-8v-12l12-9z" />
  <path id="icon-camera" class="path1" d="M9.5 19c0 3.59 2.91 6.5 6.5 6.5s6.5-2.91 6.5-6.5-2.91-6.5-6.5-6.5-6.5 2.91-6.5 6.5zM30 8h-7c-0.5-2-1-4-3-4h-8c-2 0-2.5 2-3 4h-7c-1.1 0-2 0.9-2 2v18c0 1.1 0.9 2 2 2h28c1.1 0 2-0.9 2-2v-18c0-1.1-0.9-2-2-2zM16 27.875c-4.902 0-8.875-3.973-8.875-8.875 0-4.902 3.973-8.875 8.875-8.875 4.902 0 8.875 3.973 8.875 8.875 0 4.902-3.973 8.875-8.875 8.875zM30 14h-4v-2h4v2z" />
</svg>
```

Then whenever you want to include in a `use` element.

```xml
<svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
  <use xlink:href="sprites.svg#icon-home" />
</svg>
```

(At this time, Internet Explorer has a problem with this. IE would need a different approach. If you want, I can also show what's necessary for IE)

EDIT - Cross-browser support: Place SVG sprite elements in an XML file and call them into a defs element.

XML file, named sprites.xml:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SPRITES xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path id="iconHome"  d="M32 18.451l-16-12.42-16 12.42v-5.064l16-12.42 16 12.42zM28 18v12h-8v-8h-8v8h-8v-12l12-9z" />
<path id="iconCamera"  d="M9.5 19c0 3.59 2.91 6.5 6.5 6.5s6.5-2.91 6.5-6.5-2.91-6.5-6.5-6.5-6.5 2.91-6.5 6.5zM30 8h-7c-0.5-2-1-4-3-4h-8c-2 0-2.5 2-3 4h-7c-1.1 0-2 0.9-2 2v18c0 1.1 0.9 2 2 2h28c1.1 0 2-0.9 2-2v-18c0-1.1-0.9-2-2-2zM16 27.875c-4.902 0-8.875-3.973-8.875-8.875 0-4.902 3.973-8.875 8.875-8.875 4.902 0 8.875 3.973 8.875 8.875 0 4.902-3.973 8.875-8.875 8.875zM30 14h-4v-2h4v2z" />
</SPRITES>
```

An example HTML file with Javascript to propagate the defs element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sprites</title>
</head>
<body onLoad=loadSprites()>
<svg id=mySVG width="400" height="400">
<defs id="spriteDefs" />
    <use xlink:href="#iconHome" transform="translate(100 100)" />
    <use xlink:href="#iconHome" transform="translate(200 100)" />
    <use xlink:href="#iconHome" transform="translate(300 100)" />
    <use xlink:href="#iconCamera" transform="translate(100 200)" />
    <use xlink:href="#iconCamera" transform="translate(200 200)" />
    <use xlink:href="#iconCamera" transform="translate(300 200)" />
    <use xlink:href="#iconHome" transform="translate(200 300)" />
</svg>
<script>
function loadSprites()
{
    var xmlFile="sprites.xml"
    var loadXML = new XMLHttpRequest;
    loadXML.onload = callback;
    loadXML.open("GET", xmlFile, true);
    loadXML.send();
    function callback()
    {
        //---responseText---
        var xmlString=loadXML.responseText
        //---DOMParser---
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var mySpritesDoc=parser.parseFromString(xmlString,"text/xml").documentElement ;
        var addSprites=mySpritesDoc.childNodes
        for(var k=0;k<addSprites.length;k++)
        {
           var sprite=addSprites.item(k).cloneNode(true)
           document.getElementById("spriteDefs").appendChild(sprite)
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Francis! Very nice solution! Luckily IE is not a requirement for my app!

Comment: iOS 7.1 Safari also has a problem with SVGs embedded this way when they're displayed dynamically (i.e. via JavaScript).

Comment: adding the `version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` was enough to load it into the `img` tag `src`

Comment: @Francis Can you please illustrate how to make this work with IE?

Comment: @Shyamal -- Rather than a remote file, include the 'sprite' elements in a defs within your parent svg element

Comment: Can you elaborate as I tried defs but it still doesn't work. Just FYI I want to have all svg elements in a single remote file so it would be easier to modify if needed later.

Comment: @Shyamal - Is this just an IE app, or to be arranged for all browsers? Typically, I place my 'sprite' elements in a single XML file and use XMLHttpRequest to call them into the app. I'll include an example of this in an edit to the original post above sometime later today.

Comment: To solve the problem with IE (or any other browser that fails to load the SVG), try svgxuse, a simple polyfill for referencing external SVGs in use elements: https://github.com/Keyamoon/svgxuse

Answer (score 9):

There are a bunch of different ways to embed an SVG file into a document without using inline SVG code like you did in your example markup. Moving the SVG to an external file certainly makes for much cleaner, more editable code. Chris Coyier has a great page on [Using SVG](http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) on CSS-Tricks. Here is a summary of the techniques covered in that article:

### **Using SVG as an `<img>`**

You can embed SVG files in an `<img>` tag just like you would a JPG or PNG or any other image file:

```
<img src="kiwi.svg" alt="Kiwi standing on oval">
```

You can adjust the width and height of your SVG image either with inline width and height attributes, or by targeting your SVG image in a CSS document.

Note that for security reasons, most browsers will disable scripts, linking, and other interactivity of SVG files added with `<img>` tags.

### **Using SVG as a background-image**

In your example code you appear to be using the SVG file as a content image, but just in case the SVG is serving a purely aesthetic purpose, you can use the SVG file as a background image in CSS:

```
body {
  background: url(kiwi.svg);
  background-size: 100px 82px;
  /* some other CSS probably */
}
```

Like `<img>` tags, advanced SVG features are disabled when using this method.

### **Using SVG as an `<object>`**

You can also embed an SVG file in an `<object>`. Using this technique will allow you to use some advanced SVG features like scripting:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="kiwi.svg" class="logo"></object>
```

### **Including SVG with PHP**

If you are using PHP, or some other server-side code, you can insert the SVG file into a page programmatically. This technique might be useful if you have some more sophisticated application requiring SVG files to be dynamically loaded or something. In PHP your SVG include would look something like this:

```
<?php include("kiwi.svg"); ?>
```

### **Conclusion**

There are almost certainly other ways to add SVG files to a webpage that I didn't cover here (iframe maybe?), but I hope you will find a method that works for your application in this list. Note that there are benefits and drawbacks with each method, so  do more research before picking a method. There are also some methods that should probably be avoided. For example, don't use an `<embed>` tag because it is not, and probably never will be, part of any HTML specification.

Also read [Chris Coyier's article](http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) that I mentioned before.

Comment: I've already tried these methods without any success. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: it's not helpful for svg sprite.

Comment: leo was asking how to build a svg icon system with external svg sprites, not how to embed images in a HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to generate your index.html file with the sprite files included. This is the best approach because it means your SVG icons are loaded immediately.

You can do this on the webserver with a Server Side Include:

- [Apache Server Side Include with mod_include](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html)
- For S3 and static file hosting, you can [use a pre-processor like ssi](https://github.com/mentalblock/ssi).

Comment: The problem with this is that you will sacrifice browser caching. If you are using the same SVG sprite on several pages, the sprite will be loaded again and again over the network.

Comment: @Waruyama correct; you are sacrificing browser caching and increasing the minimum page size. However, the advantage is that you are freeing up at least one HTTP request (and more if you're using multiple sprite sets or loading individual icons). Instead of taking up 2 HTTP requests to load `page.html` and `sprite-set.svg`, you're loading `page.html`. The trade-off is worthwhile if you have a few sprites or are using a lot of HTTP requests already. I would even consider inlining/server-side including CSS and JS!