# SVG fills in external file

Tags: svg

Really basic SVG question. I have read
[SVG sprite in external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993408/svg-sprite-in-external-file)
and it works fine for me to add a svg graphic, but I can't get it to work with `defs`. First the file 'defs.svg':

```
 <svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
    <defs id='patternDefs'>
          <pattern id="pattern1" 
            x="2" y="2"
            width="5" height="5"
            patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
            <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="2" class="blue" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

and then the svg in a separate file:

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="defs.svg#patternDefs"></use>
        <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="50" stroke-width="2" stroke="red" fill="url(#pattern1)" />
</svg>
```

I am looking to get the  `fill="url(#pattern1)"` part to work, as that is what is referencing the `def` in the external file.

Sorry if you think this has been answered elsewhere but I've read a ton of stuff and thought that if I could get the sprite version to work then why not a `defs` version. (I am very new to `svg`)

Comment: This has been answered by @`Robert Longson` below for firefox but answers appreciated for chrome/other browsers fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xlink:href="defs.svg#patternDefs"` should be `xlink:href="defs.svg#pattern1"`

On top of that `<use>` has to point to something to be rendered, not a pattern. If you want to fill a circle with a pattern just set the circle's fill to the pattern. E.g.

```
<svg>
    <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="50" stroke-width="2" stroke="red" fill="url(defs.svg#pattern1)" />
</svg>
```

Note that external fills are not widely supported, although they do work on Firefox for instance.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I have tried this and it didn't work. In both firefox, opera and chrome

Comment: I suppose I am thinking of using an external svg file rather like a style sheet or a graphic library. It works for graphics, I would like it to work with `defs` / pattern fills.

Comment: Hi @RobertLongson , you have said "If you want to fill a circle with a pattern just set the circle's fill to the pattern". I have done that in my example, I just want that pattern defined in an external file.

Comment: It sure works for me with your original defs.svg on Firefox per my answer. I don't know what you were trying to do with the `<use>` element so I've removed it.

Comment: The first code section in my OP is in a different file. How can removing the `use` make it work? It doesn't for me, how can the second code snippet even know what the #pattern1 is ?

Comment: Because the file name is prior to #pattern1 in the fill. Are you using Firefox?

Comment: I didn't originally have the full url in the fill. Yes it works in firefox now! Sadly not in chrome but I half expected that anyway. Thankyou