# Select SVG from 1 File With ID

Tags: html, css, image, svg, vector

I have a vector file that contains 40 svgs all in one image. Each vector has an id inside `<g>` tag and I want to know how to select a certain svg from that 1 file without selecting all the image in html.
PD: Each vector has its own dimensions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either add [this svg tag](https://pastebin.com/L0WsA0S1) into your html to have it drawn together with the rest of the html or, you could load it from a file on your server by using this

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
   <use xlink:href="path-to-your-svg:#the-id-of-the-object-you-want-to-load"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: I've written this "<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <use xlink:href="Desk SVG/All/nastifunny.svg#tea"></use>
    </svg>" inside my html code and it hasn't worked. Do you know why?

Comment: i would like to refere you to [this awnser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22996360/8040906)
it goes in more detail than i'm able to do in a propper way

Answer (score 0):

without any source i can only guess,

you could use `#the-containing-id:nth-child(n){ ... }` where # is the numerical equivalent to the svg
if it's just svgs you could use `svg:nth-of-type(n){ ... }`

also if that one particular svg has an id you can just use it's id, `#svgs-id{ ... }`

please provide more information and source so we can awnser your question more accurately

Comment: Thank you for helping me Odnh.
So I'm using these vectors: https://www.behance.net/gallery/26241257/FREE-Elegant-Vector-Kit-with-60-Workspace-Elements
in my website: https://marcelmiro2000.github.io/MarcelMiro
and I want to know how I could, instead of importing to my html file each vector using <img> tag for separate, how could I only use 1 file to import all these vectors.
Sorry if I'm explaining very badly,

Comment: @MarcelMiro let's say you use the SVG "nastifunny  without shadows and background .svg"
you can call all the elements with their ID using #(theirid) a.e.
`#iMac{transform: rotate(45deg);}`

Comment: but what would be the html code that you would use to add the svg to a website? Thanks again for the help.